# Identical balls for non-identical people

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

I have 40 identical black balls, 23 identical red balls, and 31 identical yellow balls. I want to distribute this to 12 distinct people such that each person gets at least one of each color ball. How many ways can I make this distribution?

I started with the stars and bars method.

For the 40 black balls:
$\binom{39}{11}$

For the 23 red balls:
$\binom{22}{11}$

For the 31 yellow balls:
$\binom{30}{11}$

After this I'm unsure. Do I just apply multiplication rule and multiply all three of these combinations?

Comment: Are all the balls distributed?

Comment: yes all the balls must be distributed

Comment: It's fairly traditional (and indeed respectful) to regard people as distinct; otherwise you would be more likely to see "bags", "bins" or "boxes" as the receptors of distribution.

Comment: @Joffan haha i was trying to be extra clear :)

Comment: Sure, it wasn't a criticism, just an observation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the distribution of one color of balls does not affect the other one, that means that the number of distributions for each color are independent, thus you can safely multiply all the numbers you got. I also checked your work, and I believe you got the right numbers to multiply together.